# Making a java application available on a smartphone through web browser?

Tags: java, iphone, web, mobile-website, smartphone

I have been building a java application intended to be used on a computer. I now found out that the program needs to be used through the iphone.

I am not very experienced and I'm under time pressure. I don't really know the easiest way to transition this program to iphone. Is there away to run the application through Safari on the iphone?

I've read a bit about Java Web Start but is that really useful for iphones?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Webstart has nothing to do with anything (and I think it's been removed recently). The easiest way might be to provide a web interface and access it through iphone's browser.

Comment: Can java code be run on the browser? As long as I provide another type of interface?

Comment: If you provide a web interface, the browser will display the web interface which is HTML and not Java. It requires you to modify your Java code to provide the web interface. If you've never written a webapp, it's not going to be quickly done. Especially since your desktop app wasn't designed with the web in mind, so you'll have design issues there too which can cause problems and eat into your developer time. It would still be the most straight-forward way.